# Does every automorphism of a field containing the rationals fix the rationals?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

Every automorphism $f$ fixes $1$, so every automorphism fixes the integers, and we must have $f(p/q) = f(p)/f(q) = p/q$ for $p$, $q$ integers with $q$ nonzero.

This is right, right? Also, does it generalize to extensions of fields with nonzero characteristic? Like if $A$ is the subring generated by $1$ under addition, and $F$ its field of fractions, does every automorphism of an extension of $F$ fix $F$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is right, and it does generalize. If $E$ is any field, then any automorphism of $E$ restricts to the identity of its *prime field*, which is $\mathbb{Q}$ in the case of characteristic $0$, and $\mathbb{F}_p$ in the case of characteristic $p>0$.

Comment: Does this also show that the rationals and finite fields of prime order have no nontrivial automorphisms? What about finite fields of composite order?

Comment: Yes, this is true. The Frobenius automorphism of a finite field is the identity on $\mathbb{F}_p$ because $a^p\equiv a \bmod p$.

Comment: Adding to @DietrichBurde’s comment, of your field has $p^m$ elements with $m>1$, then Frobenius is nonidentity there.